# Css crop background (both sides)

Tags: css, background

Suppose that I have background image which width = 1000px, height=1000px, my Screen width = 800px. How To trim,crop background to get -100px on left and -100px sides?

Comment: If you have a screen wider than a background image, you'll already see it cropped. Maybe you want to center your background image?

Answer (score 2):

```
background-position:center center;
```

or, if you wanted it aligned to the top:

```
background-position:center top;
```